# MongoDB NonDocker and Docker Nodes

Tags: mongodb, docker

I have a 5 node MongoDB cluster installed non-Dockerized.  I want to start adding nodes to this cluster but I want to use the Dockerized MongoDB (i.e. end result is to migrate Dockerized into the replica set and decommission the non-Dockerized nodes.)

When I do this, I am currently getting my added nodes stuck in STARTUP status so from my understanding the config files are not able to sync up.

Is there something that I need to do to prepare the cluster for the new nodes or is there some logs that I can delve into to find out why it is not moving to STARTUP2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data directory was not large enough thus the config files were unable to sync.  As soon as I grew the data directory - all was well.